# Understanding how WebApi renders results

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I am writing an API to be consumed by another team within my company. The intended format of the response needs to be JSON.

I use WebApi to construct my API. I am wondering how does WebApi know to output to JSON?

Here is one of the endpoints my API has:

```
public IEnumerable<lead> GetLeadsSinceLastPoll()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var leads = context.Lead.Where(q => q.eventID == AuthorizedUser.EventID && q.companyID == AuthorizedUser.CompanyID && q.dateAdded > AuthorizedUser.LastPollDate).ToList();
        return leads;
    }
}
```

I am testing this using Postman and in Postman the result is in JSON. Is this how the response will always be when called by client code, or is Postman doing some magic to display it in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the server that decides what format to return in. The client uses the Accept header to indicate which format it prefers to get the data in. Out of the box Web Api supports both JSON and XML. For XML you can configure the server to either use `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`.

So if you send a request with the Accept header as `application/xml` -> you will get xml. If you send it with `application/json` -> you will get json.

If you want to force a specific format when returning, use `IHttpActionResult` og similar. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) for more information.